# How can I iterate through a SQL table and select the spikes in the data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have the following table:

```
Id|name|spike|timestamp
1 |John|15   |111
2 |Jim |12   |112
3 |Jeff|13   |113
4 |Joe |4    |114
5 |Jess|0    |115
6 |Jill|0    |116
7 |Jey |13   |117
8 |Joy |15   |118
9 |Jess|14   |119
10|Joe |0    |120
```

I need to iterate through the table and select data where `spike > 10` and separate rows into different sets of data.
An acceptable query for the top table should result in:

```
Id|name|spike|timestamp
1 |John|15   |111
2 |Jim |12   |112
3 |Jeff|13   |113
```

and

```
Id|name|spike|timestamp
7 |Jey |13   |117
8 |Joy |15   |118
9 |Jess|14   |119
```

I need to process all the **spikes** in the table.

**Edit:** I don't know the number of islands in the table or how far apart they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your data into islands using a CTE to calculate rows according to timestamp and also partitioned by `spike > 10` and then taking `DENSE_RANK()` over their difference to compute the island number. You can then select from that based on the `island` number:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY spike > 10 ORDER BY timestamp) AS sn
  FROM data
),
islands AS (
  SELECT id, name, spike, timestamp,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rn - sn) AS island
  FROM CTE
  WHERE spike > 10
)
SELECT *
FROM islands 
WHERE island = 2
```

Output:

```
id  name    spike   timestamp   island
7   Jey     13      117         2
8   Joy     15      118         2
9   Jess    14      119         2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpCCwyPfoTYXEyonVknpxa/1)

Note that if you can have duplicate `timestamp` values but they do increase with `id`, you should change the `ORDER BY timestamp` clauses to `ORDER BY id`.

Comment: very neat and smart solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have an idea for number of islands then use this my *dynamic* approach solution. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nKSVxqShP7eqPBxrM2nZrG/2).

```
with cte as
(
    select
        *,
        id - row_number() over (order by id) as rnk
    from myTable
    where spike > 10
),
islands as
(
  select
      *,
      (select count(distinct rnk)::int from cte) as total_islands
  from cte
),
buckets as
(
  select
    Id,
    name,
    spike,
    timestamp,
    NTILE(total_islands) Over (Order by id) as island
  from islands
)  

select *
from buckets
where island = 2
```

for your case you can directly use window function `NTILE` which will bucket your data in two parts. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kt27X9YhSjDq6vWeLku1xi/1).

first create a cte

```
with cte as
(
  select
    Id,
    name,
    spike,
    timestamp,
    NTILE(2) Over (Order by id) as nums
  from myTable
  where spike > 10
)
```

Then run first query to get first part

```
select  
    Id,
    name,
    spike,
    timestamp
from cte
where nums = 1;
```

Output:

```
| id  | name | spike | timestamp |
| --- | ---- | ----- | --------- |
| 1   | John | 15    | 111       |
| 2   | Jim  | 12    | 112       |
| 3   | Jeff | 13    | 113       |
```

Now run the second query to get second part

```
select  
    Id,
    name,
    spike,
    timestamp
from cte
where nums = 2;
```

Output:

```
| id  | name | spike | timestamp |
| --- | ---- | ----- | --------- |
| 7   | Jey  | 13    | 117       |
| 8   | Joy  | 15    | 118       |
| 9   | Jess | 14    | 119       |
```

Comment: You could expose `nums` in the final result and get all "islands" in the same result

Comment: You should probably *not* use NTILE either, as it has to scan the entire result set to calculate its value. You can treat this as a `gaps and islands` problem, detecting the `islands` where `spike >10` in a single pass

Comment: This solution is close, but not the answer - I don't know the number of islands or how far apart they are. The presented table is used only as an example.

Comment: @inf1ux what exactly your answer should be then? I may be missing something

Comment: @zealous NTILE(N) separates data to N pieces. Number of islands is unknown. The gap size between islands is also unknown.

Comment: @inf1ux here is the second option which is more dynamic.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nKSVxqShP7eqPBxrM2nZrG/2

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to deal with gaps-and-islands problems.  In this case, a cumulative sum uniquely identifies each group.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where spike <= 10) over (order by timestamp) as island
      from t
     ) t
where spike > 10;
```

This counts the number of `spike` values *less than or equal to 10*.  This is constant for each group of consecutive "spikey" numbers.

If you want the islands enumerated, just use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by island) as grouping_number
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where spike <= 10) over (order by timestamp) as island
      from t
     ) t
where spike > 10;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1c5587ffa434ac35e65c79270b838b8d) is a db<>fiddle.